# Switching from Maven command line interface to Eclipse Plugin

Tags: maven-2, eclipse-plugin, maven-plugin, m2eclipse, compile-time-weaving

I'm working on a project that is built using maven to weave in AspectJ annotations when compiling.  Up until now, it worked like this:

1) Turn off "Build Automatically" in eclipse

2) Make changes to code in Eclipse

3) Navigate to Project folder on command line

4) Run Maven from command line

5) Refresh in Eclipse

6) Run program in Eclipse

Since Eclipse Plugins for Maven integration exist, I'd like to figure out how to use them to simplify this process.  However, I've only found instructions about how to begin a new Maven project using the plugin - nothing in any tutorials or documentation about converting an existing project.  Will I need to re-import my project?  Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Just install [m2eclipse](http://eclipse.org/m2e/), remove your maven project from your workspace, and then re-import it as an existing maven project like this:

[image: import maven project]

Comment: I'll accept this answer once I can get this import to happen without crashing